# Visual Basic Chart Annotation Blocks Scroll bars

Tags: c#, vba, visual-studio

[image]

A little background... in the image I have an annotation used for the pattern extent radius (The red dashed circle), in this chart you have the ability to zoom in by clicking on a section and dragging an area:

[image]

That's easy enough, most of the functionality for that is already setup in the chart, now on to my problem it appears the annotation essentially appears to sit on top of the chart itself, so when I draw it, it appears to 'intercept' the mouse events, so I cannot select an area within it, with the built in functionality... not the biggest issue, I rebuilt it and now that all works. So now onto my real problem, when you zoom in as in the image above, I am zoomed into a place contained within the Break radius Annotation, I believe the annotation is covering the scroll bars as they no longer can register my inputs, however if I was to zoom in...

[image]
[image]

It's just the bottom left section of both the scroll bars that don't work, I can use the buttons and such for the far ends (presumably not covered by the annotation)

What I've tried....

1) [c# chart control, vertical scrolling problems with zoom ["Stuck Scroll bar"]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837228/c-sharp-chart-control-vertical-scrolling-problems-with-zoom-stuck-scroll-bar?rq=1) I checked out this question as It seemed highly relevant, went through the pages the answer suggested and though they helped with other problems, it did not help with this problem

2) Using a series and creating my own circle manually. the Problem here is spacing the points so they are far enough away styles can be shown (dashed/dotted/solid) without them becoming one solid line, however simultaneously having them close enough together it forms a circle (when you zoom in more and more this becomes impossible), which proved unmanageable.

3) setting the scroll bars to not be docked within the chart area (there is a property for it), however in this case the scroll bars move to the left/bottom walls of the control and look silly considering they only control scrolling for the center image

4) I've checked around a bunch of other questions but none seemed to apply as well as #1 above

5) at the moment while I figure this out I have a fugded solution whereby I toggle the visibility with the middle mouse button, if the annotation is invisible it allows me to scroll (I've already tried some dumb solutions where I turn the annotation off temporarily while the mouse is pressed and stuff like that)

Anyways, is there a way with the annotation I can use those scroll bars? is there a way I can prevent the drawing of the hidden portions of the annotation? anyone else have an idea?

Comment: One possible position though not the one I quite want is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804765/mscharts-custom-panning?rq=1, and removed the scroll bars altogether, add a button to reset the zoom myself, and just allow them to pan

Comment: I assume your annotations are nor interactive (moveable). Can you draw a rec circle around the 'blind' areas so we know exactly where they are?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to add that yeah I've set all the interactive properties in the annotation (selectable, moveable, etc, to false)

Comment: I highlighted the area with a blue rectangle that the built in functionality for zooming, and scrolling would not work